# Making Multiple API Queries Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make an API query in Python to return a list of districts and their unique IDs in Indonesia.  I was able to pull data from the API and store it as JSON.

However, the API query only returns the first 100 results.  In this particular example, I know that Indonesia has 700+ districts, so it would require 7 queries (but since I don't always know how many districts are in a country, I'd like to be able to run a loop that keeps querying until all of the results are exhausted).

Ideally, I would like to make repeated queries to the API, and append the results of each query into one variable until I have extracted the full list of districts.

e.g.
Query 1: store results 1 - 100 in variable X
Query 2: append results 101 - 200 to variable X.
repeat until all results are stored.

For more information on the API, see here: https://gtmp.linkssystem.org/docs/districts

Here is the code I started:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError

request = Request('https://gtmp.linkssystem.org/api/districts?admin0=indonesia')

response = urlopen(request)
geo = response.read()

import json
geolist = json.loads(geo)
```

If this affects anything, I was hoping to write all of the results to a .csv like so:

```
import csv

with open('C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\geo.csv', 'wb') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp)
    a.writerow(["admin0id", "admin0","admin1id","admin1","admin2id","admin2","admin3id","admin3"])
    for e in geolist:
        a.writerow([e["admin0id"],
                    e["admin0"],
                    e["admin1id"],
                    e["admin1"],
                    e["admin2id"],
                    e["admin2"],
                    e["admin3id"],
                    e["admin3"]])
```

Comment: Try changing the value (I guess this is the offset) to something higher; e.g. `?admin100=indonesia`.

Comment: You need more information on the API.  I played around with it a bit, but I couldn't figure out how to send in an "offset" (i.e. 'give me the next 100 table entries starting at entry X').  I'd try contacting them and asking them how to do it, as it's not apparent from the website.

Comment: ok.. thanks.  i'll contact them and see how that works.  I'm very new to this, so i wasn't even sure how to ask the question.  It sounds like I should be looking into "offsets," so that is a helpful start.